# Objective-C / Load cell from xib / Need explanation

Tags: objective-c, nsbundle, loadnibnamed

Ok, I know how to load a custom cell from a xib, via this code:

```
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustpmCellView" owner:self options:nil];
cell = (CustomCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
```

But can someone explain what does the first row do?

I feel really stupid typing that every time and not knowing how exactly it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustpmCellView" owner:self options:nil];
```

`loadNibNamed` returns all views under your xib. So we are holding that in array. Say here all view under *CustpmCellView* will be fetched and saved in array *nib*.

```
cell = (CustomCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
```

We are getting first view from array, as that is our desired view, and then we are casting and assigning to cell object.

We need to assign new view to each cell in `UITableView`, so for that purpose every time new cell is needed, and we do that using above code snippet.

**EDIT**

`[NSBundle mainBundle]` , is explained at [What the meaning of [NSBundle mainBundle] in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3393142/what-the-meaning-of-nsbundle-mainbundle-in-iphone)

Comment: I see.... So say I would have more then 1 view in that xib, I would have to select which view I want to load?

Also, what does the [NSBundle mainBundle] do?

Comment: Exactly. Assigning TAG to View can help you in that case.

Comment: Could you explain what the [NSBundle mainBundle] part does?

Answer (score 0):

[According to Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSBundle_UIKitAdditions/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/loadNibNamed%3aowner%3aoptions%3a)

```
loadNibNamed:owner:options:
```

Unarchives the contents of a nib file located in the receiver's bundle.

```
- (NSArray *)loadNibNamed:(NSString *)name owner:(id)owner options:(NSDictionary *)options
```

**Parameters**

*name*
The name of the nib file, which need not include the .nib extension.

*owner*

The object to assign as the nib’s File's Owner object.

*options*

A dictionary containing the options to use when opening the nib file. For a list of available keys for this dictionary, see “Nib File Loading Options.”

*Return Value*

An array containing the top-level objects in the nib file. The array does not contain references to the File’s Owner or any proxy objects; it contains only those objects that were instantiated when the nib file was unarchived. You should retain either the returned array or the objects it contains manually to prevent the nib file objects from being released prematurely.